# How can i show data usage dynamic on status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

I am implementing a function in phone.

I want to show data usage dynamic on status bar.

How can i do that ?

Comment: You can use `Service` or `BroadCastReceiver`.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? and data usage?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to achieve the data usage on toolbar. If you want to achieve on status bar you need to achieve it through window manager. There is no direct api to talk to status bar

```
private long total_rcv;
private long total_send;
private long prev_upload_speed;
private long prev_download_speed;
private Handler mHandler;
private TextView networkSpeedMeter;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    networkSpeedMeter = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.networkspeed);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    if(mHandler!=null){
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        mHandler.post(runnable);
    }
}

protected void onDestroy() {
     if(mHandler!=null){
         mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
         mHandler=null;
     }
     super.onDestroy();
};      

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do the job
        final long download_speed =  (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()-total_rcv)/1024;
        final long upload_speed = (TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()-total_send)/1024;
        if(networkSpeedMeter!=null && (prev_download_speed!= download_speed || prev_upload_speed != upload_speed) ){
            prev_download_speed = download_speed;
            prev_upload_speed = upload_speed;
            networkSpeedMeter.setText( String.format("D:%4sKB/S%4sU:%4sKB/S", download_speed, "", upload_speed) );
        }
        total_rcv = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
        total_send = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        if(mHandler!=null){
            mHandler.postDelayed(this,1000L*1); /*every 1 second*/
        }
    }
};
```